# What do you call casual bekishes (or formal robes) for wearing at home or while learning

Tags: minhag, clothing, pictures

I have seen various rabbanim in video clips or in pictures that sometimes wear a type of bekishe that drapes more like a nice robe. This version of the bekishe (if that is even the correct term) seems to have no shoulder padding, looser sleeves, and less garment structure than the standard bekishes that are seen in shul on Shabbos, Yom Tov, at simchas, or at a Rebbe's tish. The later often have stiffer shoulder padding and the structure of a suit jacket, but in silk, and of course longer. I have also seen the more "casual" robe-like bekishes worn by Litvishe men while learning or receiving guests. I am interested to know what the correct term is for this kind of coat, and where they are sold at. I don't live in a community where I can just ask someone who is familiar with this type of dress.

**Here's my understanding of the various coats:**

**Rekel** = Long suit jacket. Made of wool, not silk. Meant for weekdays.
**Standard Bekishe** = Black silk, minimal design, firmer shoulder padding and lapels.
**Tish Bekishe** = Floral/Patterned silk, sometimes with blue highlights (or other colors). Meant for special events like a tish or wedding.
**Kapote** = Black silk, knee length, only 2 rows of buttons (instead of 3), long slit up the back to the waist (which bekishes do not usually have). Worn by Chabad and Litvishe rabbinim.
**Casual Robe (or whatever it is called)** = As described above, and shown in the following pictures and videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfVxlR5y1tk
https://youtu.be/BKx53ga2XJw?t=503
https://images.redframe.com/gedolim/iphoto/photos/preview/prvRav%20Moshe%20Feinstein%20-%20MDY007.jpg

Comment: these look like kapotes also known as a sirtuk

Comment: How about a "smoking bekishe"?

Answer (score 2):

'shmatte bekishe' is probably what your looking for, but the dull solid black ones (that many chassideshe bucharim wear in yeshiva) is known as a 'chalat'.